# Finding the length of a series in postgres

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

A tricky query for postgres. Imagine, I have a set of rows with a boolean column called (for example) success. Like this:

```
id | success  
9  | false  
8  | false  
7  | true  
6  | true  
5  | true  
4  | false  
3  | false  
2  | true  
1  | false
```

And I need to calculate a length of the latest (not) successful series. E. g. in this case it would be "3" for successful and "2" for not successful. Or using window functions, then something like:

```
id | success | length  
9  | false   | 2  
8  | false   | 2  
7  | true    | 3  
6  | true    | 3  
5  | true    | 3  
4  | false   | 1  
3  | true    | 2  
2  | true    | 2  
1  | false   | 1
```

(note that I generally need a length of only the latest series, not all of those)

The closest answer I've found so far was this article:
https://jaxenter.com/10-sql-tricks-that-you-didnt-think-were-possible-125934.html
(See #5)

However, postgres doesn't support "IGNORE NULLS" option so the query doesn't work. Without "IGNORE NULLS" it simply returns me nulls in length column.

Here is the closest I was able to get:

```
WITH
  trx1(id, success, rn) AS (
    SELECT id, success, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id desc) 
    FROM results
  ),
  trx2(id, success, rn, lo, hi) AS (
    SELECT trx1.*,
    CASE WHEN coalesce(lag(success) OVER (ORDER BY id DESC), FALSE) != success THEN rn END,
    CASE WHEN coalesce(lead(success) OVER (ORDER BY id DESC), FALSE) != success THEN rn END
    FROM trx1
  )
SELECT trx2.*, 1
- last_value (lo) IGNORE nulls OVER (ORDER BY id DESC ROWS BETWEEN
UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
+ first_value(hi) OVER (ORDER BY id DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW
AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
AS length FROM trx2;
```

Do you have any ideas of such a query?

Comment: This is called `gaps and islands`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the window function `row_number()` to designate series:

```
select max(id) as max_id, success, count(*) as length
from (
    select *, row_number() over wa - row_number() over wp as grp
    from my_table
    window
        wp as (partition by success order by id desc),
        wa as (order by id desc)
    ) s
group by success, grp
order by 1 desc

 max_id | success | length 
--------+---------+--------
      9 | f       |      2
      7 | t       |      3
      4 | f       |      2
      2 | t       |      1
      1 | f       |      1
(5 rows)
```

[DbFiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=26030919602bf691b4c890f5acc95539)

Answer (score 0):

Even though answer by Klin is totally correct, I'd like to post another solution my friend suggested:

```
with last_success as (
  select max(id) id from my_table where success
)
select count(mt.id) last_fails_count
from my_table mt, last_success lt
where mt.id > lt.id;

--------------------
| last_fails_count |
--------------------
| 2                |
--------------------
```

[DbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=89f3dc46b755f754f8fb29108630eff2)

It is twice faster if I only need to get the last failing or successful series.