# Counting consecutive days in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to count the number of consecutive days in two tables with the following structure:

```
| id | email | timestamp |
| -------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 1    | hello@example.com  | 2021-10-22 00:35:22 | 
| 2    | hello2@example.com  | 2021-10-21 21:17:41 |
| 1    | hello@example.com  | 2021-10-19 00:35:22 | 
| 1    | hello@example.com  | 2021-10-18 00:35:22 | 
| 1    | hello@example.com  | 2021-10-17 00:35:22 |
```

I would like to count the number of consecutive days of activity. The data above would show:

```
| id | email | length |
| -------- | -------------- | -- |
| 1    | hello@example.com  | 1 | 
| 2    | hello2@example.com  | 1 |
| 1    | hello@example.com  | 3 |
```

This is made more difficult because I need to join the two tables using a UNION (or something similar and then run the grouping. I tried to build on this query ([Finding the length of a series in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50340046/finding-the-length-of-a-series-in-postgres)) but I'm unable to group by consecutive days.

```
select max(id) as max_id, email, count(*) as length
from (
    select *, row_number() over wa - row_number() over wp as grp
    from began_playing_video
    window
        wp as (partition by email order by id desc),
        wa as (order by id desc)
    ) s
group by email, grp
order by 1 desc
```

Any ideas on how I could do this in Postgres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create an `aggregate` function in order to count the adjacent dates within an ascendant ordered list. The jsonb data type is used because it allows to mix various data types inside the same array :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_date(x jsonb, y jsonb, d date)
RETURNS jsonb LANGUAGE sql AS
$$
    SELECT CASE 
             WHEN d IS NULL
             THEN COALESCE(x,y)
             ELSE
               to_jsonb(d :: text)
            || CASE
                 WHEN COALESCE(x,y) = '[]' :: jsonb
                 THEN '[1]' :: jsonb
                 WHEN COALESCE(x->>0, y->>0) :: date + 1 = d :: date
                 THEN jsonb_set(COALESCE(x-0, y-0), '{-1}', to_jsonb(COALESCE(x->>-1, y->>-1) :: integer + 1))
                 ELSE COALESCE(x-0, y-0) || to_jsonb(1)
               END
             END ;
$$

DROP AGGREGATE IF EXISTS count_date(jsonb, date) ;
CREATE AGGREGATE count_date(jsonb, date)
(
  sfunc = count_date
, stype = jsonb
) ;
```

Then iterate on the `count_date` on your table grouped by id :

```
WITH list AS (
SELECT id, email, count_date('[]', timestamp ORDER BY timestamp :: timestamp) as count_list
  FROM your_table
 GROUP BY id, email
)
SELECT id, email, jsonb_array_elements(count_list-0) AS length
  FROM list
```